# prove this summation by case analysis

Tags: summation, proof-explanation

How would I go about trying to prove the below via case analysis?
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}$$

I understand that you'd need to split it up into two cases, when n is odd and n is even. But anything aside that I need a little help with.

Here's the notes with the incorrect proof I was working from: [Screen print of proof question and work through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVuLj.png)

Comment: If you are saying $\sum_{i=k+1}^{2k}i=2k+1-i$, well, that makes no sense, as $i$ is a dummy variable on the left, it can't show up on the right.

Comment: These are proofs directly taken from my teacher's notes. I thought it made no sense and I am so confused

Comment: It's time, then, to ask your teacher to have a look at the notes.

Comment: They take a few days to reply and I have a small test on this in the next couple days

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're up the creek without a paddle. What do you expect anyone to tell you? That we've been able to read your teacher's mind, and figure out what the teacher really meant?

Comment: Nope, I was hoping that someone could show a correct method to prove this question via case analysis

Comment: "prove this question" doesn't make sense. You can prove a theorem; you can answer a question; you can't prove a question. But it would be best if you wrote out the question here, instead of asking people to chase it offsite. There is instruction on how to format mathematics, available through the Help menu.

Comment: I'm terrible at maths, if you want to downvote the question because I don't know how to format a question properly feel free. I'm sorry that it the formatting is suboptimal. If you can have a little patience to spare with me, could you prove the theorem? I'm a software engineer, not a mathematician, but I'm trying to learn. So I'd rather not spend time doing otherwise

Comment: Looks like the teacher's mistake is forgetting the summation: we should have $$ \sum_{i=k+1}^{2k} i =\sum_{i=1}^{k}( 2k+1-i)$$. Think about  the LHS as counting forward and the RHS as counting backwards

Comment: I'm glad to see you've done well to format the equation. Not so glad to see that you've completely changed the question so a lot of what people have written in reply looks out of place. Anyway, there is absolutely no need to consider the cases $n$ even and $n$ odd separately in order to prove $\sum^ni=n(n+1)/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misreading the graphic.

To make sense of the proof in (for example) the case of $n = 2k$

First  consider that

$$\sum_{i=k+1}^{2k} (i) ~=~ \sum_{i=1}^k (2k + 1 - i).$$

The easiest way to see this is to consider that having $i$ range from
$(k+1)$ to $(2k)$, is equivalent to having $i$ range **downward** from
$(2k)$ to $(k+1)$.  Examining the terms in reverse order, you have
$(2k) + (2k-1) + \cdots + (k+1).$

This alternate perspective is consistent with $\sum_{i=1}^k (2k + 1 - i).$

The remainder of the proof in the case of $n = 2k$ is therefore valid.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how $$\sum_{i=1}^k i + (2k+1 -i) = k(2k+1)$$ ? I understand that the i's cancel each other out. But where does the k outside the bracket on RHS come from? Is it because the upper limit is k?

Comment: @user5423 For any constant $D$, $\sum_{i=1}^k (D) = [k \times D].$  Thus, $[i + (2k + 1 - i)] = (2k + 1)$, which is a constant.  So, the summation becomes $\sum_{i=1}^k (D)$, where $D = (2k+1).$

Comment: is that regardless of the lower limit i.e. if i > 1, then would we multiply by k - something?

Comment: @user5423 yes.  For example, when $5 \leq k \in \mathbb{Z^+},~\sum_{i=5}^k (D) = (k-4)D.$